# List of all Names of Java classes and it's methods

Tags: java, jvm

I am sorry for stupid question , a friend of mine need to prepare some university work , actually he chose to create java syntax editor with Javascript. He wrote kick ass Text parser platform with javascript (that will be soon avaliable for public ) , and now he need to implement autocomplete in this editor.

Is there any source avaliable where can he found all standard classes of JVM ? I mean , Name of the class and it's methods / Properties.

Comment: Why doesn't he post this question? :D

Comment: Why won't he do some research first...

Comment: Why doesn't he read the documentation? Doesn't seem to be such a kick-ass programmer if he isn't even able to find the JavaDocs.

Comment: Don't judge and woun't be judged.... He doesn't know english enough to post the question , asked me for help. Since I don't know Java I couldn't helpep him , posted question here....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a listing which is now online at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1004486/classes.txt.zip

The code used for creating it was (after find . -name *.class in the extracted folder of rt.jar):

```
public class CodeListing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("classes.txt"));

        String line = br.readLine();
        Vector<String> classes = new Vector<>();
        while (line != null) {

            line = line.substring(2);
            if (!line.contains("$"))
                classes.add(line.replaceAll("/", ".").replaceAll(".class", ""));

            line = br.readLine();
        }
        Collections.sort(classes);
        for (String c : classes) {


            System.out.println("    "+c);
            try {
                for (Method m : Class.forName(c).getMethods()) {

                    boolean first = true;
                    System.out.print("        "+c+"."+m.getName()+"(");
                    for (Class<?> t : m.getParameterTypes()) {
                        if (!first)
                            System.out.print(", ");
                        else
                            first = false;
                        System.out.print(t.getSimpleName());
                    }
                    System.out.println(") : "+m.getReturnType().getSimpleName());

                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            catch (Error e) {}
            catch (Exception e) {}
        }
        br.close();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) might be what youre searching for

Answer (score 1):

There is no such list in an easily machine-processable form.  (Yea, sure the information is in the javadocs, but you have to "scrape" it out of the HTML ... ick!!)

However, you shouldn't need such a list.  You can iterate over all of the ".class" files on the effective classpath, and use something like BCEL to extract the method names from the ".class" files.  That's better than a fixed list because:

- the sets classes and methods in the standard Java libraries change from one version to the next, and
- you want the editor to be able to do completion for other class / method names; e.g. for classes in the user's code base, and in 3rd-party libraries he / she is using.